# missing glyphs when displaying vector field in paraview?

Tags: paraview

When visualizing the file below (paraview 4.2.0 64 bit linux), not all glyphs are rendered. For instance, the glyph at [7,0,0] (corresponding to pointID 7) is missing.

Can anyone confirm that behaviour?

file.vti

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VTKFile type="ImageData" version="0.1" byte_order="LittleEndian" compressor="vtkZLibDataCompressor">
  <ImageData WholeExtent="0 7 0 15 0 0" Origin="0 0 0" Spacing="1 1 1">
  <Piece Extent="0 7 0 15 0 0">
    <PointData>
      <DataArray type="Float64" Name="thedata" NumberOfComponents="3" format="ascii" RangeMin="1.7320508076" RangeMax="221.70250337">
        1 -1 1 2 -2 2
        3 -3 3 4 -4 4
        5 -5 5 6 -6 6
        7 -7 7 8 -8 8
        9 -9 9 10 -10 10
        11 -11 11 12 -12 12
        13 -13 13 14 -14 14
        15 -15 15 16 -16 16
        17 -17 17 18 -18 18
        19 -19 19 20 -20 20
        21 -21 21 22 -22 22
        23 -23 23 24 -24 24
        25 -25 25 26 -26 26
        27 -27 27 28 -28 28
        29 -29 29 30 -30 30
        31 -31 31 32 -32 32
        33 -33 33 34 -34 34
        35 -35 35 36 -36 36
        37 -37 37 38 -38 38
        39 -39 39 40 -40 40
        41 -41 41 42 -42 42
        43 -43 43 44 -44 44
        45 -45 45 46 -46 46
        47 -47 47 48 -48 48
        49 -49 49 50 -50 50
        51 -51 51 52 -52 52
        53 -53 53 54 -54 54
        55 -55 55 56 -56 56
        57 -57 57 58 -58 58
        59 -59 59 60 -60 60
        61 -61 61 62 -62 62
        63 -63 63 64 -64 64
        65 -65 65 66 -66 66
        67 -67 67 68 -68 68
        69 -69 69 70 -70 70
        71 -71 71 72 -72 72
        73 -73 73 74 -74 74
        75 -75 75 76 -76 76
        77 -77 77 78 -78 78
        79 -79 79 80 -80 80
        81 -81 81 82 -82 82
        83 -83 83 84 -84 84
        85 -85 85 86 -86 86
        87 -87 87 88 -88 88
        89 -89 89 90 -90 90
        91 -91 91 92 -92 92
        93 -93 93 94 -94 94
        95 -95 95 96 -96 96
        97 -97 97 98 -98 98
        99 -99 99 100 -100 100
        101 -101 101 102 -102 102
        103 -103 103 104 -104 104
        105 -105 105 106 -106 106
        107 -107 107 108 -108 108
        109 -109 109 110 -110 110
        111 -111 111 112 -112 112
        113 -113 113 114 -114 114
        115 -115 115 116 -116 116
        117 -117 117 118 -118 118
        119 -119 119 120 -120 120
        121 -121 121 122 -122 122
        123 -123 123 124 -124 124
        125 -125 125 126 -126 126
        127 -127 127 128 -128 128
      </DataArray>
    </PointData>
    <CellData>
    </CellData>
  </Piece>
  </ImageData>
</VTKFile>
```

Comment: When running with paraview 4.2.0 64 bit Ubuntu on another computer, it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the **Glyph Mode** to **All Points**. In 4.2, the default is to use a sampling mechanism to attempt to get uniformly distributed glyphs.

Comment: that solved my problem, thank you. so that was an interpolation artefact.